# Scraping online PDFs with rvest

Tags: html, r, pdf, web-scraping, rvest

I want to access the data from this [train timetable web page](https://www.scotrail.co.uk/sites/default/files/assets/download_ct/_sr1705_glasgow-edinburgh_via_falkirk_highv2.pdf). Using rvest on the URL doesn't give a useful answer:

```
> read_html("https://www.scotrail.co.uk/sites/default/files/assets/download_ct/_sr1705_glasgow-edinburgh_via_falkirk_highv2.pdf")

{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <body><p>%PDF-1.5\r%\xe2ãÏÓ\r\n22 0 obj\r&lt;&gt;\rendobj\r               \rxref\r22 97\r0000000 ...
[2] <html><p>C*ÐsO\u0086ZFWM\u0086X H$\u0083&gt;\u0083-Ïs\u0086O=Ì\u008c"Lí½/1\u009c\u009fõ\u008e\u0 ...
```

However when I save the source code locally as an html file I can scrape the contents just fine:

```
> read_html("/path/to/this/file/_sr1705_glasgow-edinburgh_via_falkirk_highv2.html")
{xml_document}
<html dir="ltr" mozdisallowselectionprint="" moznomarginboxes="">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta charset="utf- ...
[2] <body tabindex="1" class="">\n    <div id="outerContainer">\n\n      <div id="sidebarContainer"> ...
```

I'd like to scrape using the URL rather than manually downloading and saving as a html file. It feels like I'm missing something fundamental about PDFs. I'm confused that the file extension in the URL is .pdf but F12 reveals html.

Is there a way to scrape directly from this URL? If not why does saving locally 'fix' the issue?

Comment: `read_html()` gives you rubbish, because you are trying to read a pdf file as html. You can use `download.file("https://blablabla.pdf", "save_here.pdf")` to save PDFs

Comment: Where do you get the first URL from? Do you have the URLs of all online PDF documents?

Comment: I just navigated to the first URL using the website. The number of documents is small enough for me to get the other URLs in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all URLs saved in the vector called `my_urls`, you can then iterate through it and tell `R` to download those files.

```
my_urls <- c("www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf", 
             "che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf",
             "www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf")
save_here <- paste0("document_", 1:3, ".pdf")

for(i in seq_along(my_urls)){
  download.file(my_urls[i], save_here[i])
}
```

Or perhaps a bit more elegantly, using `mapply()`:

```
mapply(download.file, my_urls, save_here)
```

After execution, you will see that there are three PDFs called `document_1.pdf`, `document_2.pdf` and `document_3.pdf` saved in your working directory.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer with my question. I'm specifically wondering why the pdf at that URL has html source code. Maybe I'm missing some fundamental knowledge about pdfs or the web. My goal (if it's possible) is to the access the html source code using rvest so I can avoid downloading files.

Comment: How exactly do you get that HTML source code of your PDF file?

Comment: This is in firefox:

1. Browse to the first URL.
2. Press F12 and go to DOM and style inspector.
3. Rclick the top html node: Copy -> outer html.
4. Paste into a text editor.
5. Save file with .html extension.

Comment: I see. That is not the HTML of the PDF document, it is the HTML code of your online PDF-viewer. I think it will be (nearly) the same for any other PDF document you open like that. If you want the content of a PDF document, you will have to download, as far as I know.

Comment: It seems like I need to choose between easy parsing or easy downloading. The nice thing about using the html code of the online pdf-viewer is it looks easier to parse. Each individual data point is enclosed in it's own div. Using pdftools to extract from a pdf file produces a single long string which would be difficult to parse.